# What are the parent compounds of the following?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: What are the parent compounds of the following chains of carbon atoms?]

I just need these two answered correctly so I have examples to work with, also if someone could label the longest continuous chain, that would be great too!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Find the longest chain by starting at one end of the molecule and counting the number of carbon atoms along each possible path.  I've attached a figure with numbering of the longest chain.  Hopefully it will answer your question and you will understand how to find and number the longest chain.  In the future, post your thoughts, so we can better understand how to help.

[image]